# Sprout Forms and Multi-site on Craft 3

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutforms

Is it at all possible to get forms to display per site and not all forms displaying to a site admin user? Also an admin user doesn't seem to be able to run reports on there own site, without being an admin of the entire Craft CMS instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/multi-site.html

Looks like multisite support for Sprout Forms is a planned/under review addition